# How to integrate nodejs in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, node.js, codeigniter, web-applications

I want to integrate node.js in codeigniter framework but I am having confusion that how to execute node.js in codeigniter.I have knowledge about codeigniter but nodeJS is still quite new for me.

How do I integrate nodejs in my existing website which is in codeigniter?

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: node.js is used to create server and you can use that. I guess you have no idea about nodejs better to go to docs.

Comment: @Jai Is there any documentation for install nodejs into codeigniter?

Comment: You can't install nodejs into codeignitor as it is not available for views. Nodejs is basically a server you can start the server and on basis of that you can use any framework not sure about codeigniter you can have a look at http://expressjs.com

Comment: they require separate servers. what is it that you want to accomplish?